# Selection for specific special character

Tags: r, special-characters

I am on Windows, using R 3.0.2 (2013-09-25) – `Frisbee Sailing`
I used package `XLConnect` to import an Excel table into a `df` called `ConsolFLAT`.
The Excel table contains rows that are totals which I want to filter out.
Rows that are totals can be identified by a character "■" as the first character in the `GLDESC` column, i.e. `GLDESC` has a row with the value "■cash" which is a total line for all cash, I want to filter these out.

I was able to create a column `TOTALS` in my data frame that just has the first character with:

```
 ConsolFLAT$TOTALS<-(substring(ConsolFLAT$GLDESC,1,1)
```

I now want filter my dataframe for all rows for which this `TOTALS` column is not equal to "■"
I can't find the character "■" in the ASCII list, but in Excel "code ("■") returns "63"
My problem is that I am unable to get R to identify this character, i.e. as.character ("■") returns:[1] "¦"

How do I set up in R a subset function against the character "■"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ConsolFLAT[ConsolFLAT$TOTALS != intToUtf8(9632),]
```

or

```
grep(paste0("^", intToUtf8(9632)), ConsolFLAT$GLDESC, invert=T, value=T)
```

Comment: Thanks! This works, tried to +1 you but don't have enough reputation.
In any case, thank you so much, struggled with this for a while, appreciate this. D

Comment: you are welcome. I don't wanna know how much time I spent with such character/encoding things in the past. It's always a pain. ;)